# Devise: Editar conta sem precisar confirmar senha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Olá, este é meu problema: tenho uma aplicação(rails 4) com a `gem 'devise'` e `gem 'omniauth-facebook'`. Quem se loga com o facebook na hora de editar a conta aparece o erro "current password can't be blank'... Desse modo eu gostaria de desabilitar essa necessidade de confirmação de senha oara se editar a conta. Eu sei que o devise tem este tutorial de como fazer isso: [Tutorial](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-edit-their-account-without-providing-a-password)

Mas eu não entendi muito bem quais passos são necessários para fazer isso, sou novo em programação, e do jeito que estou fazendo não ta dando certo! Obrigado!

Comment: Tem como você colocar o seu código do controller?

Comment: Tem sim augusto, aqui está http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24463479/devise-update-account-without-password-confirmation !

Comment: Massa. Também sou iniciante, mas você chegou a tentar colocar minha sugestão abaixo? Tenho ela rodando em uma aplicação e funciona perfeitamente. **Obs: Utilizo apenas o Devise **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que você poderá fazer o seguinte:

O método **update** do controller de Usuários poderia ser assim:

```
def update
  if user_params[:password].blank?
   @user.update_without_password(user_params_without_password)
  else
   @user.update(user_params)
  end

 if @user.valid?
  if @user == current_user
    sing_in(@user, baypass: true)
  end
  redirect_to admin_users_url
 else
  render action: 'edit'
 end
end
```

Onde esse *user_params_without_password*  é um método privado:

```
def user_params_without_password
    user_params.delete(:password)
    user_params.delete(:password_confirmation)
    user_params
 end
```

E o *update_without_password* é um método pronto do próprio **Devise**